# 'ExtensionAttribute' is ambiguous in the namespace 'System.Runtime.CompilerServices'

Tags: .net, vb.net, compilation

I have vb project in .net 2.0. I converted the  project to .net 4.5. 
I have This error

```
'ExtensionAttribute' is ambiguous in the namespace 'System.Runtime.CompilerServices'.
```

What I have to do

Comment: This may be the problem described and answered in this post: [BC30560: 'ExtensionAttribute' is ambiguous in the namespace 'System.Runtime.CompilerServices'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12104883/bc30560-extensionattribute-is-ambiguous-in-the-namespace-system-runtime-comp/49883228).

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution for my problem, I will post it :

1. Close VS.
2. Restart your IIS
3. Clear the "C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.NET\Framework\XXX\Temporary ASP.NET Files\" folder.
4. Clear the project's Bin.
5. Rebuild your application.

Comment: Proper answers quote the source of the solution.  Just copy/pasting a solution that's already well documented elsewhere is *not* useful, it gives anybody with the same problem *more* web pages to look through for no benefit.