# How to resolve BC30560: 'ExtensionAttribute' is ambiguous in the namespace 'System.Runtime.CompilerServices'?

Tags: c#

I want to use **MediaToolkit** from **Nuget Package Manager** and in my test projects, the tool worked fine in VB.NET and C#.NET project. However, when I use it in my real project (which has been upgraded many times to higher version in VB.NET), I am always receiving an error attached screenshot. In my test project and real project, both are in .NET 4.6.

```
                        string videoPath = Server.MapPath("~/Video/" + fileUpload.FileName);
                        var inputVideoFile = new MediaFile { Filename = videoPath };
                        using (var engine = new Engine())
                        {
                            engine.GetMetadata(inputVideoFile);
                        }

                        duration = inputVideoFile.Metadata.Duration;
```

Could you please help me to resolve the issue?

[image]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [BC30560: 'ExtensionAttribute' is ambiguous in the namespace 'System.Runtime.CompilerServices'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12104883/bc30560-extensionattribute-is-ambiguous-in-the-namespace-system-runtime-comp)

Comment: the first step is to find what assemblies are declaring this type, which you *should* be able to do at the IDE. The ideal approach would be "drop one of them", but that isn't always possible; if it isn't, it becomes an "extern alias" problem, which is ... tricky

Comment: You have a method that is in two different libraries ( same name).  So you have to specify the library (namespace) as well as the method name.  So you need to use something like System.Xml.Linq  where system is one library xml is another library (or different namespace in the library) and Linq is a third library (or namespace).

Comment: This is because another namespace already contains a routine/extension (you have more than one, so it conflicts) with that name, so it can be either `Engine` namespace and or `Mediafile` namespace. To overcome this, just alias them and use that alias.